# URL Parameter Pointing to HTML Element Value

Tags: hyperlink, href, url-parameters

I was wondering if it's possible to reference the value of an html element through a URL parameter?

A use case for this would be if I want to link to something another website was linking to, like a google drive or drop box download link. By embedding a link within a link like this I can send someone a download link with some inherent sense of trust that it's not malicious if the recipient now knows the download link was posted by the owner of a specific website.

There could be more uses for this as well but that's my particular use case right now.

Haven't been able to find a way to do this yet, and actually don't think this possible, but wanted to double check by asking here first.

I know you can reference a particular spot on a page by using the hashtag sign at the end of a url, like this `https://something.com/#element-name-x`

So what I guess I'm looking for is something like if an `<a>` tag has an id/name of "where-to" and an href value of "wherever.com" I'd be looking to do something like `<a href="https://somethingelse.com/#where-to{href}">Click the Link</a>`, where clicking "Click the Link" at something.com wouldn't take you to somethingelse.com#where-to but it would go directly to wherever.com

Comment: I shouldn't have posted this at 2am, making this comment to bump it up now that we're in usual working hours in the western hemisphere

Comment: Well I think I thought of a workaround but it seems janky and not very ellegent. If I have some Javascript running on the intermediate page looking for a query string parameter that gives the id of some html element that is either an `<a>` tag or has a child `<a>` element. If parameter is found query that `<a>` tag's href value and run `window.location.replace("href_value")` to redirect to the end destination without further input from the user.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not sure how to make it more clear but how about this. Link Y exists on y.com, I want to share Y with someone but retain the assurances I'm not sending a malicious link by showing the link I'm sending exists on y.com. Rather than have the person I'm trying to share Y with personally navigate to y.com first, then find Y and click on it, I'd like to have a shareable link for y.com that has some sort of parameter that locates Y and auto redirects to Y without actually loading y.com